# How to view error page provided in Blazor WASM (ASP.NET Core hosted) template?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

Note, this is the ASP.NET Core Hosted template. So it has a:

- client project
- server project
- shared project

I'm a little confused as to why the template returns an error razor page when an exception occurs in the server project.

`program.cs`:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

But yet the Blazor client cannot process it. I see the html as the response in the inspector though.

How do I go about displaying a razor page if I'm using Blazor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `server project` uses Razor Page as an error page because it is a `Web App` project itself.

We do not recommend that you use `Razor Pages` in **Blazor apps**. But you can host `Blazor components` in a **Razor Pages app**. If you host the app component of the Blazor app, you're actually hosting the entire Blazor app in the Razor Pages app.

In fact, a Razor page `.cshtml` is pretty much the same thing as a Blazor page with the `.razor` extension- it’s the same syntax etc just a different execution approach.

If you want to be able to customize the error page, such as error details, you can create your own Blazor component and display the error using Cascading Values.

You would of course have to handle the errors with a try catch block and populate the error message and stack trace into your custom Blazor component.

For example:

Create an Interface:

```
public interface IErrorComponent
{
    void ShowError(string title, string message);
}
```

Change `FetchData.razor` and `MainLayout.razor`:

FetchData.razor:

```
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "ErrorComponent")]
    protected IErrorComponent ErrorComponent { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/notfound.json");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorComponent.ShowError(e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@implements IErrorComponent

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @if (isErrorActive)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" @onclick="HideError">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3>@title</h3>
                    <p>@message</p>
                </div>
            }
            <CascadingValue Value="this" Name="ErrorComponent">
                @Body
            </CascadingValue>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>


@code {
    bool isErrorActive;
    string title;
    string message;

    public void ShowError(string title, string message)
    {
        this.isErrorActive = true;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void HideError()
    {
        isErrorActive = false;
    }
}
```

This way you can add your detailed error message in the page:
[image]

For more details, here are two documents for reference:

[Blazor common error component](https://nightbaker.github.io/gitflow/azure/piplines/2020/01/22/blazor-error-component/).

[Global exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#global-exception-handling).

It is worth mentioning that, if there is an error in `server project` and you want to display `Error.cshtml`, you need to pay attention to whether you are in a `Development` environment at that time, if so, then you need to add `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` to the corresponding position:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

**Edit:**

You can set the `forceLoad` parameter to `true` to bypass client routing and force load the requested page, but you still need the try catch module to catch exceptions.

For example, you throw an exception in your controller:

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Here is an error!");
}
```

Then use `try...catch...`in `FetchData.razor` to catch the exception:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
//....
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string Url = NavigationManager.BaseUri.ToString();
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(Url+"Error", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

This will force redirection to the `Error` page when an exception is thrown.

Comment: thanks for the response. It still would make more sense to not even include that as the default in a Blazor app since as you said we shouldn't even use it. It's very confusing for someone starting out.  As for the development environment exception handler, even if an error is thrown in the server, the error page doesn't get retrieved in the client, at least not for me for the reasons you stated. Are there specific  cases where it will populate? I've been testing by throwing exceptions in the controllers.

Comment: Hi @cjadd7, I update my answer. You can check it.

Comment: Hi @cjadd7, is this what you want?

Comment: hi @Chen , I ended up just making an error page in client instead of navigating back to the server for the Error.cshtml but will mark this as answered since it helped me understand it a bit better.